# Easiest way to grant edit access to a field for one user on case object without creating a new profile?

Tags: case, permission-sets, field-level-security

I was curious if anyone knew the easiest way to grant edit access to a field for one user on case object without creating a new profile?  I am using an existing profile that has cred setup to allow access and edit to numerous fields on case, but I want to create a permission set to only allow edit access to one field while using that profile.  I created a permission set and only checked the edit box on that field, but it still allows editing of all other fields when I login as that user and view a case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Permission Sets are *additive* to base Profile permissions. You need to start by restricting access to *all* fields on the profile, then create 1-2 permission sets to allow access for fields to edit.